# How can I say for the last record i want to append a ". " instead of a comma? 

Tags: android, cursor

this is my code, i see here I am appending a comma between each row. for the last row i want to append a full stop instead of a comma, any ideas of how i could do that?

```
while(!cursor2.isAfterLast()) {
String mIngredientName = cursor2.getString(1) + ", " ;
                al.add(mIngredientName);
                cursor2.moveToNext();
            }
```

I have an idea in that it involves if statements but I'm unsure any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(!cursor2.isLast()) {
String mIngredientName = cursor2.getString(1) + ", " ;
                al.add(mIngredientName);
                cursor2.moveToNext();
            }
String mIngredientName = cursor2.getString(1) + ". " ;
                al.add(mIngredientName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're now testing for "if isAfterLast()".  Instead (or additionally - your choice) test for "if isLast()".  Everything before "isLast()" gets a comma, "isLast()" gets a period ... and then close your cursor.

EXAMPLE:

```
while(!cursor2.isLast()) {
  String mIngredientName = cursor2.getString(1) + ", " ;
  al.add(mIngredientName);
  cursor2.moveToNext();
}
String mIngredientName = cursor2.getString(1) + "." ;
al.add(mIngredientName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!cursor2.isAfterLast()) {
  char delimitor = (if !cursor2.isLast())? "," : ".";
  String mIngredientName+= cursor2.getString(1) + delimitor ;
  al.add(mIngredientName);
  cursor2.moveToNext();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine also for "recipes" with only one ingredient (!):

```
cursor2.moveToFirst();
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(cursor2.getString(1)); 
while(!cursor2.isLast()){
    cursor2.moveToNext();
    strBuilder.append(", ").append(cursor2.getString(1));
}
strBuilder.append('.');

String allIngredients = strBuilder.toString();
```

Note that using StringBuilder is more efficient for string concatenation.